ret = (function(arg), E_OK)
In the below C code, I do not know when FUN(xxx) == E_OK could be unsatisfied, e.g. some error to fun1(xxx)? Besides, I do not know how to describe (xx, yy) statement in the C language.
#define FUN(arg) (fun1(arg), E_OK)

//...
{
    if(FUN(xxx) == E_OK)
    {
        //...
    }
}


Are you asking when/whether it's possible for FUN(xxx) == EOK to be false?

This looks like a dirty hack to bypass the return values of a function for whatever reason. Maybe part of a debug build when not all resources the program needs are available?

I wonder why anyone would come up with such a thing. One could just drop the if and ignore return value instead of that beast. Are there some intermediate levels of macros used that might result in FUN being something different? Or some conditional definitions?


#define FUN(arg) (fun1(arg), E_OK)
FUN(xxx) == E_OK could be unsatisfied,

It is not possible as it uses , (comma operator). When used in the expression the result of the last operation is used which in this case is E_OK.

I do not know how to describe "(xx, yy)" statement in C language.

It is called comma operator
C standard: 6.5.17

The left operand of a comma operator is evaluated as a void
expression; there is a sequence point after its evaluation. Then the
right operand is evaluated; the result has its type and value.97) If
an attempt is made to modify the result of a comma operator or to
access it after the next sequence point, the behavior is undefined.

